# Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am having troubles with retrieving an integer value from Query builder of Laravel. It gives me this error as the title of the question:

```
Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int
```

i tried to use also the pluck() method but with the same error.

Here is the code portion of code:

```
 Scegli Corso: <select name="tipo" id="selezionaCorsoIscrizione">
                       {{ $corsi_scii = DB::table('corsoscii')->select('idCorso','nome')->get() }}
                       {{ $post_corso = DB::table('corsoscii')->select('membriMax')->pluck('membriMax') }}
                                    
                       <option value="" selected="selected"> Seleziona Corso
                       </option>
                        @foreach($corsi_scii as $corso_scii)
                        <option value=""> 
                        @if($post_corso == 0)
                           {{ "Il corso ha raggiunto la capienza massima" }}
                        @else
                            {{ $corso_scii->idCorso." - ".$corso_scii->nome }}
                        @endif
                        </option>
                        @endforeach
```

Comment: Don't put any DB queries in your view. It's bad separation of concerns. The view should not be responsible for getting the data, only for showing the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pluck()` returns a collection of the field you selected. You can't compare it to `0`. Use `value()` instead, it returns the first available value or null.

Replace this line

```
{{ $post_corso = DB::table('corsoscii')->select('membriMax')->pluck('membriMax') }}
```

with

```
{{ $post_corso = DB::table('corsoscii')->select('membriMax')->value('membriMax') }}
```

Comment: The error was `pluck()` i used `value()` instead as you suggested, now the problem is that i want to delete on dropdow menu selection the courses that have 0 places left. the condition seems right but now it prints all places have reach the limit, even if is not the case in this part of code. `@if($post_corso == 0) {{ "Il corso ha raggiunto la capienza massima"}}`

Comment: Ok we found the new solotution for our problem, thnak you so much